# setMyLocationEnabled во фрагменте

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api

Раньше в активити где распологал свою карту добавлял атрибут `setMyLocationEnabled` а также для него permission'ы. Теперь использую данный атрибут во фрагменте, и жанный метод не работает.

```
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно корректно поправить для правильной работы данного атрибута?

Answer (score 0):

Замените для фрагментов `ActivityCompat` на `ContextCompat`

Comment: Изменил, но к сожалению значок по прежнему не появился.

Comment: @Inkognito, а собственно разрешение от юзера получено? А то вы его не запрашиваете, вроде.

Comment: да, + у меня активити с методом который описал в вопросе, и в той активити отображается значок.

Comment: Видать магия какая-то. Пройдитесь дебаггером, посмотрите не включен ли instantRun